# Skip characters in "find" output

Tags: linux, bash

I'm writing a bash script which in a certain part of the process should list the files in a directory older than 1 day and print the list to a text file to work with it later. This is the current command I have:

```
find . -mtime +0 > list.txt
```

The problem with this command is that it prints the filenames preceded by "./", e.g.:

```
./file1
./file2
./file3
```

How can I do to print only the filenames in this way?

```
file1
file2
file3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use extra binary commands if your `find` supports it:

```
find . -mtime +0 -printf '%f\n' > list.txt
```

When targeting files, just add `-type f`:

```
find . -mtime +0 -printf '%f\n' -type f > list.txt
```

Or if you intend to show the files and directories in a specified directory:

```
find some_dir -mtime +0 -printf '%f\n' -mindepth 1 > list.txt
```

Comment: I like this best, but you also need `-type f` for same reason I did.

Comment: +1; the best solution, IF `-printf` is supported (it is not part of POSIX). GNU `find` does support it. Others?

Comment: Is it `-type f` really necessary? I tried the first command without that argument and it printed only the filenames and not the directory.

Comment: @ManueldelaFuente Perhaps if you don't have directories in it or that you don't need to exclude them.

Comment: @konsolebox Well, I thought what @trojanfoe said in the other answer was that to run the command without `type` would also print the parent directory, which I found odd, though maybe I misunderstood. Anyway, all answers help me but I'll take this one, thank you so much. :D

Answer (score 3):

Use `basename`:

```
find . -mtime +0 -type f -exec basename {} \; > list.txt
```

(the reason for the `-type f` is because otherwise the searched directory is printed).

Comment: @mklement0 *Accidental* compliance... :)

Comment: I appreciate the confession :)

Comment: @mklement0 Maybe I'm just naturally POSIX-compliant, without even realising :D